# How to show that $\log 2(1/2\log 2\log 4 + 1/3\log 3\log 6 + \dotsb) + 1/2\log 2 - 1/3\log 3 + 1/4\log 4 - \dotsb = 1/\log 2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, ramanujan

I've been studying Ramanujan's work and I stumbled upon this question in the book: Collected Papers of Srinivasa Ramanujan. In there I found [question  number 769](https://books.google.com/books?id=h1G2CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA333) which is about an infinite sum with logarithms. I didn't found a solution, so can someone please explain it to me:

> Show that
>
> $$\log 2\left(\dfrac1{2\log 2\log 4} + \dfrac1{3\log 3\log 6} + \dfrac1{4\log 4\log 8} + \dotsb\right) + \dfrac1{2\log 2} - \dfrac1{3\log 3} + \dfrac1{4\log 4} - \dfrac1{5\log 5} + \dotsb = \dfrac1{\log 2}.$$

Comment: The link in your post goes to page 327 with questions 463-507. Perhaps you ment to link to [page 333](https://books.google.com/books?id=h1G2CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA333)?

Comment: 769 is prime :-)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459198/can-you-solve-question-number-769#comment1189765_459198), thanks for the corrected link!  Since the question was better inlined anyway, I fixed the link while transcribing it.

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

Observe that the left-hand side is the sum of two convergent series. Let $N\geq 2$ be an integer tending to infinity. Truncate the first series at the $N$-th term and the second series at the $2N$-th term. The resulting finite sum $S_N$ equals
\begin{align*}
S_N&=\sum_{2\leq n\leq N}\frac{\log 2}{n\log n\log 2n}+\sum_{2\leq n\leq 2N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n\log n}\\
&=\sum_{2\leq n\leq N}\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}-\frac{1}{n\log 2n}\right)+\sum_{\substack{2\leq n\leq 2N\\\text{$n$ even}}}\frac{1}{n\log n}
-\sum_{\substack{2\leq n\leq 2N\\\text{$n$ odd}}}\frac{1}{n\log n}\\
&=\sum_{2\leq n\leq N}\frac{1}{n\log n}-2\sum_{\substack{4\leq n\leq 2N\\\text{$n$ even}}}\frac{1}{n\log n}+\sum_{\substack{2\leq n\leq 2N\\\text{$n$ even}}}\frac{1}{n\log n}
-\sum_{\substack{2\leq n\leq 2N\\\text{$n$ odd}}}\frac{1}{n\log n}\\
&=\sum_{2\leq n\leq N}\frac{1}{n\log n}+\frac{1}{2\log 2}-\sum_{\substack{4\leq n\leq 2N\\\text{$n$ even}}}\frac{1}{n\log n}-\sum_{\substack{2\leq n\leq 2N\\\text{$n$ odd}}}\frac{1}{n\log n}\\
&=\frac{1}{\log 2}+\sum_{3\leq n\leq N}\frac{1}{n\log n}-\sum_{\substack{4\leq n\leq 2N\\\text{$n$ even}}}\frac{1}{n\log n}
-\sum_{\substack{2\leq n\leq 2N\\\text{$n$ odd}}}\frac{1}{n\log n}\\
&=\frac{1}{\log 2}+\sum_{3\leq n\leq N}\frac{1}{n\log n}-\sum_{3\leq n\leq 2N}\frac{1}{n\log n}\\
&=\frac{1}{\log 2}-\sum_{N<n\leq 2N}\frac{1}{n\log n}.
\end{align*}
Estimating the last sum crudely, it follows that
$$\frac{1}{\log 2}-\frac{1}{\log N}<S_N<\frac{1}{\log 2}.$$
In particular,
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} S_N=\frac{1}{\log 2}.$$
Of course this limit equals the left-hand side in the original question, hence we are done.